# UrlFetchApp.fetch only returning part of page source

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to record the page source of a url using UrlFetchApp.fetch but am not able to record the full thing. The string cuts off after roughly 8KB of text.

I'm using a google apps script to record the follower counts of some Instagram accounts. It works by splitting out the follower count from the page source. It suddenly stopped working two days ago on the 12th December after working for weeks.

When I log the content text I see the problem is that only part of page source is being recorded. The script now falls over as the follower count is further down the page source than what gets recorded in the string.

How can I get the full page source into a string? Is there a limit on what I can get using UrlFetchApp.fetch?

```
function test(){
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post'
  };

  //I get the same issue whether or not I include the options variable to make it a POST request.
  var instaPage = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.instagram.com/barackobama", options).getContentText();

  Logger.log(instaPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the method `Logger.log` that trims the output string, not `UrlFetchApp.fetch`. If you want to see the entire variable `instaPage`, one quick way is to place it in a spreadsheet cell:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(instaPage);
```

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I didn't check that! You're right, that was the issue. I found the script was actually falling over because of a typo, which I've now corrected.